# Trying to make a map using plotly.express with crash data for massachusetts. and its saying can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

Hi like the title says I keep getting the can only concatenate **str (not "int")** **to str** and sometimes i also get **unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'**. I'm assuming this is happening on the **lon** and **lat** line and I don't know how to fix it. help would be appreciated.

```
import plotly.express as px 
import pandas as pd 
    
data = pd.read_csv("2023_Crashes.csv", on_bad_lines='warn', dtype = object)
    fig =  px.scatter_mapbox(data,
    lon = data['LON'],   
    lat = data['LAT'],    
    zoom = 10,
    color = data['NUMB_FATAL_INJR'],   
    size = data['NUMB_VEHC'],    
    width = 1200,   
    height = 900,    
    title = 'Car Accidents'    
)
```

I just want to get through this error so i can input the coordinates.

Comment: Add the error stack trace if you're looking for help in debugging. Also, have you checked your source dataframe? Does it have consistent data types in the columns you're using?

Answer (score 0):

`int` and `str` are two different data types in python. Using the `+` operator for `int` is addition while for `str` it's concatenation (eg. `'a' + 'b', will output 'ab'`). You're using certain operands that contain `str` and `int` as mixed inputs which is causing these errors. You'll need to convert the data to a uniform data type in order to perform these operations:

```
#if you require numerical operations
data['LON'] = data['LON'].astype(float)
data['LAT'] = data['LAT'].astype(float)

#if you require string operations
data['LON'] = data['LON'].astype('string')
data['LAT'] = data['LAT'].astype('string')
```